# parallel_cucumber gem (part of parallel_tests) ... How do I run all individual scenarios in parallel

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I can easily run *features* in parallel like so:

`$ bundle exec parallel_cucumber features/ -n 6 -o '-t  @smoke -t ~@manual'`

I want to all *scenarios* in parallel, however as that would be much faster.

How can I do this with the parallel_cucumber gem?

Answer (score 0):

I did this some time ago but without parallel_cucumber gem.

- Cucumber accept this: `cucumber features/test.feature:7` - run test on specific line number of given feature file.
- `grep -rHn` helps you generate list of path/file:line_number
- [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) available in most distros helps you execute the list
- parsing of output is needed :-(